# How to make vector graphics image using python

Tags: python, numpy, vector-graphics, image-preprocessing

I am trying to make a project to convert an image to a vector graphic image, how can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just get the vector matrix of an image (too simple). But I'm confuse how can I work with this to make a vector image. Can you help me to understand the process? Thank you

Comment: Have a look at PIL (python image library), I am sure there is a way to accomplish what you need using it.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with numpy, please remove this tag

Comment: Yes I already looked on that, but I couldn't find anything helpful

Comment: This is a complex problem, please provide an exemplary image. For black&white bitmap images you can try AutoTrace.

Comment: @tstanisl can you share the references please?

Comment: @Fake_Death http://autotrace.sourceforge.net